# How can I count up without using any loops?

Tags: java

How can I go about counting up without using any of the iterative programming loops like while, for, do, for-each, etc?

Something like this:

```
void countUp(int start, int end){
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific? You could probably use recursion, and you should probably change the `return` type of the method.

Comment: what about using lambdas??

Comment: Could you define limit of counting ? If there is limit then you could do with recursion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count up using recursion. Search it if you don't know how it works out. So where end>start this is how it would work. There are a lot of things you can do with recursion. Notice my base case is when start==end then it stops counting.

```
public void countUp(int start, int end){
 if(start>=end){
   return;
 }
 System.out.println(start++);
 countUp(start,end);
}
```

Comment: if(start>=end) should be if(start>end) otherwise, end number would not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
void countUp(int start, int end){
  if(start <= end)
    countUp(start+1, end);
}
```

Thus, you check if your start is less than end and recursively call the same function with new value of start (start+1)

Answer (score -1):

Although I really, really do not know why are you going to do that...
    int count(int start, int end) {
        if (start == end) return start;
        return count(++start, end);
    }

This may cause a stack overflow if you recurse too deeply, namely if a range is too wide. for some reason the above code reminds me of c++ metaprogramming idioms.

Comment: Ohh, looking at other answers, ++start is not needed, start+1 is a better idea.

Comment: There are many reasons why one should use recusion. If you tell someone that doing x is a bad idea, tell them why x is not as good as another option, link them to some information that could help them find a better option than x, and tell them why the task y which you suggest instead is a better idea.

Comment: I didn't actually express an opinion, I just said I do not know a reason for using it in that specific case. I didn't even try to say that recursion is useless.

Comment: You said "I really, really do not know why you are going to do that", however there are good reasons to do that. Perhaps they are learning recursion. EIther way, you should back up your case. You talked about his task like it shouldn't be done. Why shouldn't it? Explain.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is that in this specific case, there is a possibility of having stack overflow just by using a too wide range.

Comment: Don't tell me, I'm not the one who needs more information about recursion.

Comment: In any case, the danger of stack overflow was noted in the answer from the beginning. I clarified it a bit few minutes ago.